# An if else in a mat-cell Angular 8

Tags: angular, if-statement, mat

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="tipalabra">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Tipo palabra</mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.tipalabra}} </mat-cell>
```

row.tipalabra returns or T or E, if it is T I want it to put "Text" in mat-cell and if it is E "Expression"

I've seen how to do it and only examples appear with if but not with else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
    {{row.tipalabra == 'T' ? 'Text' : 'Expression'}}
</mat-cell>
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to add it with template.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="tipalabra">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Tipo palabra</mat-header-cell>
      <ng-container *matCellDef="let row">
        <mat-cell *ngIf="(<your condition>); else <yourElseTag>"><your Text></mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-template #yourElseTag><Your Expression></ng-template>
    </ng-container>
```

I am not sure, but logically it sounds to be working!